# PHP: image*() - functions provide invalid images

Tags: php

Following code:

```
class FilesController extends Controller {
  public function icon($fileId) {
    $this->uses("FileAttachment");
    $FA = new FileAttachment($fileId);  
    $fnth = $FA->path . 'th___' . $FA->filename;  
    $this->View->render = false;

    if (file_exists($fnth)) {                        
        $imageinfo = getimagesize($fnth);

        switch ($imageinfo[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($fnth);                                    
                Header("Content-type: image/jpg");
                imagejpeg($image);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($fnth);
                Header("Content-type: image/gif");                                            
                imagegif($image);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $image = imagecreatefrompng($fnth);                                                           
                //Header("Content-type: image/png");
                imagepng($image);
                break;  
            case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
                $image = imagecreatefromwbmp($fnth); 
                Header("Content-type: image/bmp");                   
                imagewbmp($image);
                break;                  
          }      
    }
    imagedestroy($image);        
  }
}
```

produces broken images. The image is shown in a browser just as a broken one. The file exists, otherwise there would come nothing. My Windows shows the pictures correctly. What can be the cause?

PS. If I remove Header, the browser displays the image's binary content, so it actually looks OK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is rather pointless - you're forcing PHP (and gd) to do a bunch of useless work to load up the file, decompress it into memory, and then recompress it for output.

Why not simply have:

```
$info = getimagesize($path_to_file);
header('Content-type: ' . $info['mime']);
readfile($path_to_file);
```

?

As for your code, check the entire output of the function. If there's ANY php warnings/errors being produced, they'd get embedded in the output and general cause "corrupt" images.

Comment: It didn't work. The image is still broken. There are no warning or errors, just binary stuff, if I ommit header(). Any other idea?

Comment: Ok I have found the problem. There are several space characters before the output. I must find out where they come from. But I accepted your answer because you have proposed another good way to realize the function. Cheers

Comment: You need to clean your buffer, just use ob_start(); and ob_end_clean();

Answer (score 2):

`imagecreatefromgif();` //returns an image resource

Have you tried to add at the bottom ?

```
readfile($image);  //reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.
```

Comment: note the `imageigf()` call right AFTER the imagecreatefromgif() call, and ditto for all of the other types.

Comment: @MarcB: No, it's not true

Comment: There is not reason to do it.